# Event Handling in a PDF form

Tags: java, pdf

I want to handle keystroke events in a existing editable PDF form using java.

I tried to do this with PDFBox and still unable to achieve the target. Is there any other java related  API that have capability to handle such events in PDF form fields?

edit:
In my case I want to handle events in AcroForm using Java. (PDF viewer: JPDFviwer)

Comment: *handle keystroke events* - in which PDF viewer? If in some Adobe Reader version, you can try using JavaScript (JavaScript may be disabled, though). Depending on the use case a custom Adobe Reader plugin may be more appropriate. In other viewers JavaScript may or may not be an option, and also viewer-specific interfaces may or may not be.

Comment: @mkl: I want to access PDF form fields using java and handle form field events like what we do in java swing. I've already manipulated a PDF form using Apache PDFBox API, but unable to find a way to handle such events.

Comment: If you want to do it in Java, you surely use a Java PDF viewer. Which one is it?

Comment: @mkl: I think I misunderstand the problem :(. Is it depends on the pdf viewer? Then, can you give  me any directions of that?

Comment: You can only handle key stroke events where there are key strokes, and there only are actual key strokes in a PDF viewer. (Our do i misunderstand you and you want to emulate something? )

Comment: My problem is like this; I have a editable pdf form. Then, while I typing some text on that, I want to track it using java program. That's the requirement. So, How I do it? (Thank you for your reply; It should depends on the PDF viewer) I expect an answer like "use x pdf viewer with x API".

Comment: I'd advice you to edit your question to include these information. But you also should think about preferences concerning the choice of viewer. E.g. On which platforms do you need the viewer to run? Linux? Android? MacOS? Windows? What kind of pdf Form do you have? AcroForm? XFA?